# Getting error :ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Club is a model there I store student class information.

I have the following associations:

```
    class Club < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :mcqs
    end

    class Mcq < ActiveRecord::Base

    #validation
    validates :topic, presence: true,length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :club, presence: true

    #association
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :club
    end
```

And here is my Club Controller-

```
class ClubsController < ApplicationController

def student_show_index
    @club = current_user.clubs
  end

  def student_show_topic
    @club = current_user.clubs
    @mcq = @club.mcqs
  end

end
```

I just want to print all the MCQ of a particular Club to a student.

Here is my view that show Topic of MCQ(student_show_topic).

```
    <%= render 'assessment/type' %>
<h1>List of Topics</h1>
<div class="main-cont">
    <div class="stream-cont">
        <div class="stream-cont">
        <% @mcq.each do |f| %>
            <div class="feed-cont-title all-header">
                <tr>
                    <td><%= f.topic %></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is association problem. my club model can't access mcq model.

Here is my error messege.

```
NoMethodError in ClubsController#student_show_topic
undefined method `mcqs' for #<Club::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fb031e0cf48>
Extracted source (around line #81):

79 def student_show_topic
80  @club = current_user.clubs
81  @mcq = @club.mcqs
82 end
83
84 end
```

After that I use @mcq = @club.first.mcqs

It show all the Mcq of that club. but in my Club table I assign club as a

1. 9-physics
2. 9-chemistry

so I want when I click on 9-physics topic it show only physics mcq topics and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look you `@club` is not a single object it a collection of object, You can not call `mcqs` with `@club`.

But you can call `@club.first.mcqs`

Comment: This is wrong `mcq_ids = @club.collect(&:mcq_id)` as per the associations

Comment: Yes, his code is very confusing. but what he is expecting something like this

Comment: You should remove those two queries as they are completely wrong!

Comment: wow. its working. I'm new on RoR. so can you please give more info about how '.first' is working.

Comment: `.first` pick the fist object/element from an `array`, Like if you `arr = [1, 2, 3]` then `arr.first` will return `1` `arr.last` will return `3` etc. you can read form api.rubyonrails.org

Comment: I assign club as - 1.' 9A physics' 2. '9B chemistry'. but when I click on topic link. it show all topic of 9A. I just want it show topic by club_id. like when I click on 9A physics it show only topic of 9Aphysics (club_id=1).